# Select the max length column which contains userID - Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called tblLineage which contains two columns as below

```
|  USERID  |        REPORTING PATH           |
----------------------------------------------
|  LB123   |  AD324/RB567/LB123              |
|  KS654   |  AD324/RB567/LB123/KS654        |
|  RG110   |  AD324/RB567/LB123/KS654/RG110  |
```

The reporting path shows the userIDs of each employees line managers up to the Director

I am attempting to find the number of levels that report to each individual by working out the difference between the length of that persons reporting path and the max length of any reporting path that contains that persons userID

e.g. in the table above user LB123 has Len([Reporting Path]) = 17
and the maximum length of any reporting path which contains his userID is 29 (difference of 12). I can then infer that he has two levels reporting to him (as a userID plus a preceding slash is 6 characters).

I am trying to write an sql query that will give the max reporting level for each user

I have tried doing something like this...

```
SELECT 
    t1.userID, 
    Len(t1.[Reporting Path) AS LenPath, 
    Max(Len(t2.[Reporting Path])) as MaxPath,
    (MaxPath- LenPath)/6 as Rank
FROM 
    tblLineage t1 INNER JOIN tblLineage t2 ON t1.userID like "*" & t2.[Reporting Path] & "*"
GROUP BY 
    t1.userID, t1.[Reporting Path]
```

But it is not returning any results. Can anyone see where I am going wrong (or suggest a better approach)?

Comment: If you simply stored the line manager ID you can use a recursive CTE to provide the full recursive management path and the level they are at. In Access you would have to create a function to do that as it doesn't really support recursion.

Comment: Hi Minty. Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have explored that option. I was hoping there was some way to do this with pure sql as I am trying to find the fastest way to do this in Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JOIN` condition is backward.  Try:

```
FROM tblLineage t1 INNER JOIN
     tblLineage t2
     ON t2.[Reporting Path]  like "*" & t1.userID & "*"
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course. What a silly mistake. Out of interest I don't suppose you can think of any other way of doing this without a wildcard? It is running incredibly slowly

Comment: @Leroy . . . You can try asking another question.